# How do I render React on Wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, create-react-app

**Im trying to get a React app to render as a part of a Wordpress page.**

I created my app using `create-react-app` and added

```
"homepage": "."
```

to `package.json` before building.

At first I tried out the functionality by embeddning the necerssary core-files in a standard html document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

<div id="wp-root"></div>

<script src="runtime-main.363857b3.js"></script>
<script src="main.ef284662.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="2.319ef205.chunk.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**And sure enough it worked!**

When approaching Wordpress I enqued the script-files in `functions.php`.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/2.319ef205.chunk.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.ef284662.chunk.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/runtime-main.363857b3.js', true);
```

I also enqued a simple test script `alert("test")` in the same folder to make sure it was responding.

My test script fired on every page as expected, so I went ahead by including my `<div id="wp-root">`  on a page, and for science in the `header.php` just under the body-tag

My test script works and my React build works in the `index.html` test.

**Why won't Wordpress render it?**

create-react-app: 3.4.1
wordpress: 5.5.3
theme: Blankslate

Comment: Is there something in Wordpress that prevents something in React by default? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This worked!**

If I load the scripts from a remote host direcly in to the `footer.php` just before `</header>` it works prefectly!

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script src="http://localhost/react_app/build/static/js/runtime-main.363857b3.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/react_app/build/static/js/main.ef284662.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/react_app/build/static/js/2.319ef205.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
```

I also tried importing the React CDN successfully, but that didn't solve the issue.

This might be an issue with the way `wp_enqeue_scripts` works. In this case it just ignored all the scripts exept `test.js`